# Is there a native technique in PostgreSQL to force "timestamp without time zone" to not include milliseconds?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.17. (Migrating from MySQL)

A java program writes dates inside a table. The date formats is the following:
`2019-01-01 09:00:00`

But it can also be `2019-01-01 09:00:00.00` or `2019-01-01 09:00:00.000` when inserted in the database, which messes up my date management in my program when retrieved.

On insertion, I would like all the date to have the very same format: `2019-01-01 09:00:00`. The datatype used by the column is `timestamp without a time zone`.

**How can I tell postgresql to not input milliseconds in `timestamp without timezone` via configuration or SQL query ?**

This [data types doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) does not provide any information about that.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: if you are migrating today, you should use the current Postgres version (12), 9.6 is somewhat "dated".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

> time, timestamp, and interval accept an optional precision value p which specifies the number of fractional digits retained in the seconds field. By default, there is no explicit bound on precision. The allowed range of p is from 0 to 6

So just define your column as `timestamp(0)`, e.g.:

```
create table foo
(
   some_timestamp timestamp(0)
);
```

If you have an existing table with data, you can simply ALTER the column:

```
alter table some_table 
   alter column some_timestamp type timestamp(0);
```

If you now insert a timestamp with milliseconds, the value will be rounded to remove the milliseconds.

Note that technically you still have milliseconds in the stored value, but they are always set to `0`

Comment: Thanks. Just for curiosity: when comparing these timestamps, does it compare with the milliseconds or without when the bound is set to 0 ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain: it compares the milliseconds (which are `0`)  as well

Answer (score 0):

You can `cast`:

```
mytimestamptz::timestamp(0)
```

This will *round* the result to the nearest second. If you want to truncate instead:

```
date_trunc('second', mytimestamp)
```

Comment: Good to know, but I prefer @a_horse_with_no_name solution as it is a "one time only" manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Retrieve as a timestamp and in the application querying the database, manage the precision however you want. eg. via JDBC you'll get a Java LocalDateTime object, in Python you'll get a datetime object.
2. If you want to retrieve timestamps as strings, there are lots of [formatting options available](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

   ```sql
   SELECT to_char(when, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM mytable
   ```
3. Drop any milliseconds on input by specifying the [precision option to your timestamp type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html):

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE mytable (..., when TIMESTAMP(0));
   ```